# Cannot set property 'height' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the `height` of a `div` by getting the `height` from another `div`, but i'm getting the error `Cannot set property 'height' of undefined`.

The Code:

```
$("#loading_image_container").style.height = $('#content_frame').height();
```

I'm sure the height of the content_frame is 500px.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$("#loading_image_container").height($('#content_frame').height());
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're referencing a jQuery object, not a DOM element. Either use the in-built jQuery function as follows:

```
$("#loading_image_container").height($('#content_frame').height());
```

Or, get the DOM element first:

```
$("#loading_image_container")[0].style.height = $('#content_frame').height();
```

Comment: Why? There is no need to knit-pick that syntactic issue. 'Inbuilt', 'or 'in-built' is a British synonym of built-in from 1923 > http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inbuilt. Now please go and troll someone else's answer.

Comment: Also, could someone explain the reason for the downvote please?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set the `style` of a jQuery object, use CSS

```
$("#loading_image_container").css("height", $('#content_frame').height());
```

Or:

```
$("#loading_image_container")[0].style.height = $('#content_frame').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(".div1").css({'height':($(".div2").height()+'px')});
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you miss .style in right expression:
Try to

```
  $("#loading_image_container").style.height = $('#content_frame').style.height;
```